# Github API not always returning content-length header

Tags: python-3.x, github, github-api

When I make a request to the github api, the response headers do not always contain the content-length header.

Sometimes it returns this:

```json
{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://render.githubusercontent.com', 'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=TheAmazingJeh-McSaveFiles-679514d.zip', 'Content-Length': '230360822', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox", 'Content-Type': 'application/zip', 'ETag': 'W/"43b5092d176697371a0d15d5f1e12f1cdac5d6c1ca0950d70cd4721b75105ead"', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'Vary': 'Authorization,Accept-Encoding,Origin', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'deny', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Date': 'Wed, 03 
May 2023 09:19:37 GMT', 'X-GitHub-Request-Id': '9000:EF57:66D0E6:834C83:64522729'}
```

but other times it returns this

```json
{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://render.githubusercontent.com', 'content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=TheAmazingJeh-McSaveFiles-679514d.zip', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox", 'Content-Type': 'application/zip', 'ETag': 'W/"43b5092d176697371a0d15d5f1e12f1cdac5d6c1ca0950d70cd4721b75105ead"', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'Vary': 'Authorization,Accept-Encoding,Origin', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'deny', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Date': 'Wed, 03 May 2023 09:17:49 GMT', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'X-GitHub-Request-Id': 'B1D9:06BC:5CB241:72F20E:645226BC'
```

The first code block contains a `Content-Length` header, but the second does not. Is there any way to force it to include one?

This is the code I have at the moment

````py
def download_zip(GITHUB_REPO, branch, zip_path, autoDownload=True):
    """Downloads a zip file from a Github repository
    
    autoDownload: If True, the file will be downloaded automatically. If False, the file will be opened in the browser, and the user will have to download it manually"""
    headers = {
        "Authorization" : f'{GITHUB_TOKEN} ghp_r5***',
        "Accept": '*.*',

    }

    g = Github(GITHUB_TOKEN)
    OWNER = g.get_user().name
    EXT = "zip"
    url = f'https://api.github.com/repos/{OWNER}/{GITHUB_REPO}/{EXT}ball/{branch}'

    if autoDownload:
        print(f"Requesting download for {c(branch, 'purple')} from {GITHUB_REPO}")
        
        for i in range(5):
            r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
            if r.headers.get("Content-Length") is not None: break
            print(f"Retrying... {i+1}/5", end="\r")

        if r.status_code == 200:
            print(f"Request successful, downloading file {c(branch, 'purple')}.{EXT}")
            with open(f'{zip_path}\\{branch}-download.{EXT}', 'wb') as f:
                total_length = r.headers.get('Content-Length')

                if total_length is None: # no content length header
                    prRed("No content length header. File size will guessed.")
                    total_length = len(r.content)
                dl = 0
                downloaded_kb = 0
                total_length = int(total_length)
                total_length_kb = int(round(total_length / 1024))
                for data in r.iter_content(chunk_size=4096): # 4096 bytes
                    downloaded_kb += int(round(len(data)/1024))
                    dl += len(data)
                    f.write(data)
                    done = int(50 * dl / total_length) 
                    prANSI(f"  [{'=' * done}{' ' * (50-done)}] {downloaded_kb} kb /{total_length_kb} kb (~{int(round(total_length_kb/1024))} mb)", 222, end="\r")
            prGreen(f"Downloaded {branch} from {GITHUB_REPO} ({downloaded_kb} kb)                                         ")
        else:
            print(r.text)   
            prRed("Error downloading file")
    else:
        prPurple(f"Opening {url} in browser")
        webbrowser.open(url)```
````

Comment: Why is the missing content-length header a problem? Your code doesn't show how you're trying to use it.

Comment: I didn't include the whole function, I have updated it now :)

Comment: It's still not clear why the missing content-length header is a problem; you can download the file without knowing the content length in advance. You just read from the content until you reach the end. You can't produce a %-complete sort of status bar in that case, of course, but you could just use a barber-pole style progress bar instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the second response, there is a header called `Transfer-Encoding` which is set to chunked. This means `Content-Length` is not returned.
By setting the `Accept-Encoding` header to `None` you will always get a `Content-Length` in the return type.

Source: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3953